# Dynamically add attribute to input element

Tags: angular, angular6

I'm creating a bunch of `input` elements via an `*ngFor` statement, and on some of them I want to add an `data-bv-integer="true"` attribute, and on some I don't.  Whether it appears or not is based on a property of the `*ngFor` item.

Is that possible to do?

I tried to add `[attr.data-bv-integer]="false"` as a test to see if that would remove the item but it doesn't.

Answer (score 4):

This is how you can dynamically add attributes to an HTML element with angular:

`[<<attribute>>]="<<condition>> ? '<<if true>>' : '<<if false>>'"`

In your case it would be:

`[attr.data-bv-integer]="shouldShow() ? 'true' : null"`

Note: null will remove the attribute

EDIT: Added "attr." thanks @ConnorsFan

Comment: Except data-bv-integer isn't defined on `input` and so that's a runtime error.

Comment: @Gargoyle - He forgot the `attr.` prefix.

Comment: Ah, so it's not `false` to remove it, it's `null`.  I was so close :)

Comment: @Gargoyle have you tried using `type="number"`?

Comment: An alternative syntax would be: `[attr.data-bv-integer]="condition || null"`.

Comment: @A.S.I am using number, but some are decimal and some are integer, and Safari doesn't play well with the number type either.